# Infinitives of purpose with the past perfect

Tags: infinitives, past-perfect

In the sentence:

> "There were people everywhere. They thronged the streets, choking the
> alleys. They had come in their thousands to see the light show"

I would group the infinitive of purpose and past perfect together, so that the sentence refers to a plan formed prior to the events of the story. At the same time, the arrival itself takes place before the crowds assemble and begin 'thronging'.

Is my analysis off?

EDIT: I apologise. I had to cut this short before clarifying. The sentence seems to be referring both to the arrival *and* a preformed plan.

Comment: The sentence is okay. I'd use "in **the** thousands". Was that the question?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I am not sure I understand the purpose of the post...

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Nah. *in **the** thousands* [briefly had some prevalence in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+came+in+their+thousands%2Cthey+came+in+the+thousands&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) back in the 70s (no idea why, since it didn't happen with BrE, [nor did it happen *anywhere* with *they came in their **hundreds***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+came+in+their+hundreds%2Cthey+came+in+the+hundreds&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "In the" is the common form of this expression [in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+their+thousands%2Cin+the+thousands%2Cin+their+millions%2Cin+the+millions%2Cin+their+hundreds%2Cin+the+hundreds&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3). It seems to be quite common [in BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+their+thousands%2Cin+the+thousands%2Cin+their+millions%2Cin+the+millions%2Cin+their+hundreds%2Cin+the+hundreds&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3), too.

Comment: Yes, an adjunct of purpose. Note that "in order" can be inserted: "They had come in their thousands in order to see the light show". Past perfect is fine for the reason you say.

Comment: Are you asking about the use of the past perfect here? It is correct. They are already in the streets, and they came there before that. They came [in order] to see the light show (infinitive of purpose).

Comment: @TinfoilHat many thanks, yes I was asking whether it was referring to both the purpose and the time of arrival.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: Your charts are too broad-based. [This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+came+in+their+thousands%2Cthey+came+in+the+thousands&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=30)  is the exact usage chart for ***they came in the/their thousands***, from which it's obvious that ***the*** is a minority choice even in AmE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I excluded "they came" because the fixed expression is "in the [plural number]", which can be preceded by a great variety of words. I suspect that adding "they came" may reduce the sample size enough to make the comparison less valid. (I can't be sure, though.)

Comment: *in their thousands* sure sounds British to my AmE ears. [in their hundreds​/​thousands​/​millions](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/in-their-hundreds-thousands-millions)

Answer (score 2):

It's not *inherently* the case that ***to see the light show*** must be an "adverb of purpose". On the basis of context and logic we can safely assume that in OP's *specific* example, the people who arrived had in fact set off with the intention of seeing the show, but consider...

> *Veterans came home **to find themselves unwelcome**...*

...where the "result" specified in the infinitive clause definitely wasn't the *purpose* of the returning veterans.

Not every "infinitive clause" in such contexts is an "adverb of purpose". Sometimes it just specifies an *outcome* (intended or not).

Comment: I may be in a muddle, but I believe the OP is conflating "infinitive of purpose" with some preformed plan...or did I misunderstand? I VTCed for "lack of clarity or details".

Comment: i upvoted your *not sure I understand the purpose of the post* comment, but then I guessed maybe he was just seeking confirmation that *Do [main verb] **to** [verb2]* always means ***in order to** [verb2]*. But sometimes that's not true - you have to take account of the specific context to see whether an outcome was *intended*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand that it isn't always the case. In this instance specifically, it seems to be referring both to their arrival and their intention.

Comment: @Ecstaticblenderboogie: It's one thing to say *Those words mean X because that's what that construction **always** means*. It quite another thing to say *Those words mean X because that's the meaning that makes most sense **in the given context***. I'm not much interested in the second situation being asked about here on ELU, because common sense and "correct interpretation in context" are "language-independent" anyway.

Comment: "Infinitive of purpose" is a descriptive term, but it's not a recognizable construction. When I was teaching ESL I always used _stopped smoking_ and _stopped to smoke_ as a contrasting pair -- one untensed clause was a complement and the other expressed an intention instead of a result. The same is true for the terms _provisional nominalization_  for "seed the lawn" and _privative nominalization_ for "seed the pepper"; the verb phrases can't be distinguished by form, only by meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm looking at this primarily from a pedagogical perspective. I agree that the context is quite clear however.